# What is the big O of this loop?

Tags: c++, loops, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

As a beginner programmer, I've always had trouble noticing the complexity of sometimes simple code. The code in question is:

```
k = 1;
while (k <= n){
    cout << k << endl;
    k = k * 2;
}
```

At first, I thought the complexity was O(log n) due to the k = k*2 line, and I ran the code as a test and kept track of how many times it looped in regard to the size of n, which was relatively low for even large sizes of n. I also am pretty sure that it is not O(n) because it would have taken much longer to run, but I could be wrong there, as that is why I'm asking the question.

Thanks!

Comment: _"I also am pretty sure that it is not O(n) because it would have taken much longer to run"_ How did you run and measure?

Answer (score 2):

It is O(log n).
Each Iteration, k doubles - which means that in (log n) iterations it will be equal or greater than n.

Comment: Isn't it log base 2 of n?

Comment: It is. When talking about (log x) in programming - people mean (log base 2 of x)

Comment: @Winter In general - it doesn't matter. Just like O(2n) = O(n).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius So we can't assume _that in (log n) iterations it will be equal or greater than n._

Comment: @ShayLempert Do you have any source for that? In C, log means ln and log10 is log base 10. Log base 2 doesn't have as much usages as ln and log10

Comment: It is discarded in notation so there's no distinction between logarithms of different bases. So you can't tell _that in (log n) iterations it will be equal or greater than n._ A correct statement would be _that in (log2 n) iterations it will be equal or greater than n._ Or just don't say that statement, because that's not an accurate depiction of what big O is anyway.

Comment: You are right. It is more correct to say "in (log2 n) iterations it will be equal or greater than n". But what I said isn't false if you understand conventions...

Comment: What you said is outside conventions, you are misleading someone into an incorrect calculation. If I take my calculator and take the log of 2 (or use a C program) I won't get the number of iterations needed for k to be greater of equal than n.

Answer (score 2):

In your example k doesn’t increase by 1 (k++), it doubles every time it runs which traverses the loop in log(n) time. Remember that logarithms are the opposite operation of exponentiating something. Logarithms appear when things are constantly halved or doubled such as k in your example

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested, the provided example would be O(log n) due to the fact that *k* is being multiplied by a constant regardless of the size of *n*. This behavior can also be observed by comparing the necessary traversals of two very simple test cases.

For instance, if `n = 10`, it's easy to demonstrate that the program would then iterate through the loop 6 times.
Yet if you double the value of *n* so that `n = 20`, the program will only require one more traversal, whereas you would expect a program that is O(n) to require roughly twice as many traversals as the original test case.

Answer (score 1):

```
Example: 1~9

       1
     /   \
    2     3
   / \   / \ 
  4   5 6   7
 /           \
8             9
```

The deepth of the tree(or focus on 1 2 4 8...) is alsways ⌊O(logn)⌋+1, so the complexity is O(log n)